# How can I make a logo have a negative space stroke in Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, logo, transparency, stroke

I have this logo ↑
[image: Original Logo]

and I want its stroke to be negative/transparent so that it can look like this  ↓
[image: What I want it to look like.]

How do I do this in Inkscape?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have 2 overlapping paths with a heavy black stroke, and want to remove the strokes and anything behind the strokes.

Let's call your 2 paths P1 and P2.

- Select them both and duplicate (<kbd>ctrl-D</kbd>), to produce duplicates P1d and P2d.
- Keep these duplicates selected and call *Path -> Stroke to path*. This will convert the strokes of P1d and P2d into black hollow paths.
- Select P2d and duplicate it; we'll need it twice. Now you have P1, P2, P1d, P2d and P2dd.
- We don't want strokes on the final figures, so select P1 and P2 and remove the stroke (stroke width 0, or no stroke paint).
- Select P1 and P1d, and call *Path -> Difference* (<kbd>ctrl--</kbd>). This will remove the area used by the black frame P1d from P1.
- Select P2 and P2d, call *Path -> Difference*. This will remove the area of the black frame from P2.
- Select P1 and P2dd, call *Path -> Difference*. This will remove P2's black frame from P1.

Now you are done. You may want to group or combine the 2 resulting paths into a group or a single path respectively.

Comment: While your answer is a good step by step, you may want to consider adding some screenshots.

Comment: FWIW, alternatively, after "stroke to path", you could "union" the two (black) stroke paths, duplicate once, and then differ from each of the original (coloured) paths.